# table User has no column named USERNAME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO User(USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Logcat

> **Error** inserting USERNAME=raj PASSWORD=raj
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table User has no column named USERNAME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   User(USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES (?,?)

Code

```
package com.example.aaru.sqlapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase.db";
    public static final String TABLE = "User";
    public static final String UNAME = "USERNAME";
    public static final String PASS = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String ID = "UID";

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        //create database when we create DBHelper object
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        //create table
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE+"(" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + UNAME + " text," + PASS + " text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        //Delete table if table is already exists
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public long insert(String uname, String pass){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(UNAME, uname);
        values.put(PASS, pass);
        return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems with your code.

First, your `onCreate()` nor `onUpgrade()` are not getting executed. The database file is already at version 1. You can uninstall your application to remove its old database file. [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

That would then trigger a `NullPointerException` since `db` is not initialized. `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` need to use the `SQLiteDatabase` passed in as parameter to the method, not a field that has not yet been initialized.